# Property matrix elliptic operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-operators

Let $A(x)=(a_{i,j}(x))_{i,j=1}^n$ such that

- $A$ is bounded and
- $A$ is strictly elliptic, i.e. 
  $$
  \xi\cdot A\xi=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{i,j}(x)\xi_i\xi_j\ge \lambda |\xi|^2
  $$
  for a.e. $x\in\Omega$,$\forall\,\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
  Then I have to prove that $\exists\, m\in\mathbb{R}$ and a matrix $K(x)$ such that
  $$
  A(x)=m(I+K(x))
  $$
  where $\|K(x)\|_{op}\le k<1$ for a.e. $x\in\Omega$.

Idea:

let's show that $$
|\eta\cdot(I-\frac{A(x)}{m})\xi|\le k<1 \label{C}
$$
for every $\xi,\eta\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|\xi\|=\|\eta\|=1$.

Finally I will have to solve an optimization problem to find $m$.

Any help to solve \ref{C}?

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric, the strict ellipticity is equivalent to saying that $A$ is positive definite and hence has real and positive eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ such that $\lambda_{\max}\geq\lambda_i\geq\lambda=:\lambda_{\min}>0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. Take $K:=I-\alpha A$, where 
$$\tag{1}0<\alpha<2/\lambda_{\max}$$
(so that $A=\frac{1}{\alpha}(I-K)$), and show that the eigenvalues $\mu_i$ of $K$ are contained in the open interval $(-1,1)$.

By using the spectral decomposition, we have that for each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ there is a corresponding eigenvalue $\mu_i=1-\alpha\lambda_i$ of $K$. Therefore, the eigenvalues of $K$ are located in the interval
$$
[1-\alpha\lambda_{\max},1-\alpha\lambda_{\min}].
$$
From (1), we have
$$
1-\alpha\lambda_\max>1-\frac{2}{\lambda_\max}\lambda_\max=-1
$$
and
$$
1-\alpha\lambda_\min<1-0\cdot\lambda_\min=1.
$$
Since the 2-norm of a symmetric matrix is equal to its spectral radius and the eigenvalues of $K$ are located in $(-1,1)$, it follows that
$$
\rho(K)=\|K\|_2<1.
$$